# Using PostGIS functionalities in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: postgis, sql-server-spatial

I'm using Postgresql 8.4, Postgis 1.5 for My GIS works.
Planning to change my Database to Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Can we use all the Postgis functionalities in Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MS SQL Server includes spatial functions, but the functions are usually named differently, for example PostGIS's intersect function is named ST_Intersect and in SQL Server it is called STIntersection.

Your best bet to migrate would be to use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to move your data from Postgres to MS-SQL, then you'll have to re-write any queries you're using in Postgres.

Comment: Dear HeyOverThere thank you for the replay. Can you provide me the list of equivalent Postgis functions in SQL Server.

Comment: I doubt that there is a list of the differences, @RamRamesh. PostGIS has a lot more functions, though, even more than SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Correct, PostGIS has more functions and supports more features, especially non-vector data.  I don't have a direct comparison but you can check out the manuals for the two databases:  http://postgis.net/docs/ and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx have lists of all functions that each database will support.

Comment: Dear alexgleith thank you for the replay.. i'm doing routing, and so many other features using with the help of Postgis. but,now we have some requirement to change all the Database and functionalities to SQL Server 2012. So, can't we do all the functions and features in SQL Server 2012? mostly i'm using setsrid(),st_x(),st_y(),st_shortestline(),st_distance(),st_dwithin(),st_routing_xml_creator(), functions in my application.

Comment: There is no pgRouting and projection transformation features in MS SQL (that i know) if there is, they are commercial products.